# Capture deadline timestamp based on date in agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-capture

I want to capture things with a deadline timestamp relative to the date that is open in my agenda view.  How can I do that?

The `%T` template inserts today's date.  I want a template that queries my agenda view for the date and uses that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The current date in an agenda view is kept in the buffer-local `org-starting-day`. Use a sexp like `%(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" (org-time-from-absolute org-starting-day))` in your capture template to insert a date string.

Answer (score 1):

With the cursor on the desired date in the agenda view, press `k` (for kapture).  This will cause anything referring to the current day (for example `%T` in a capture template) to refer to the date in the agenda instead.

Comment: In spacemacs, this is `K` (upper case)